# how to output results of python parallel computing (ipython-parallel or multiprocessing) to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, ipython-parallel

Simple question: all tutorials I've read show you how to output the result of a parallel computation to a list (or at best a dictionary) using either ipython.parallel or multiprocessing.

Could you point me to a simple example of outputing the result of a computation to a shared pandas dataframe using either libraries?

http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/distributed-processing-pandas.html - this tutorial show you how to read the input dataframe (code below), but then how would I output the results of the 4 parallel computations to ONE dataframe please?

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

LARGE_FILE = "D:\\my_large_file.txt"
CHUNKSIZE = 100000 # processing 100,000 rows at a time

def process_frame(df):
        # process data frame
        return len(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        reader = pd.read_table(LARGE_FILE, chunksize=CHUNKSIZE)
        pool = mp.Pool(4) # use 4 processes

        funclist = []
        for df in reader:
                # process each data frame
                f = pool.apply_async(process_frame,[df])
                funclist.append(f)

        result = 0
        for f in funclist:
                result += f.get(timeout=10) # timeout in 10 seconds

        print "There are %d rows of data"%(result)
```

Comment: Why don't you place your output into one list and reduce it to one data frame like `reduce(lambda x,y: x.append(y), your_list)` ?

Comment: You need to show us what you're trying to do, show us your single-threaded solution and how you intend to multiprocess it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parallelize apply after pandas groupby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187759/parallelize-apply-after-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 2):

You are asking `multiprocessing` (or other python parallel modules) to output to a data structure that they don't directly output to.  If you use a `Pool`, from any of the parallel packages, the best you are going to get a list (using `map`) or an iterator (using `imap`).  If you use shared memory from `multiprocessing`, you might be able to get the result into a memory block that can be accessed via pointer through `ctypes`.

So the question then would be, can you pull results from an iterator or from a block of shared memory into a `pandas.DataFrame`?  I think the answer is yes.  Yes, you can.  However, I don't think that I've seen a simple example of doing so in a tutorial… as it's not that simple to do.

The iterator route seems much less likely, as you'd need to get `numpy` to digest an iterator without pulling the results back into python first as a list.  I'd go with the shared memory route.  I think this should give you an output into a `DataFrame` which you can then use in `multiprocessing`:

```
from multiprocessing import sharedctypes as sh
from numpy import ctypeslib as ct        
import pandas as pd

ra = sh.RawArray('i', 4)
arr = ct.as_array(ra)
arr.shape = (2,2)
x = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

Then all you'd have to do is pass the handle to the array to `multiprocessing.Process`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
p1 = mp.Process(target=doit, args=(arr[:1, :], 1))
p2 = mp.Process(target=doit, args=(arr[1:, :], 2))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Then, with some pointer magic, the result should filled in your `DataFrame`
.

I'll leave you to write the `doit` function to manipulate the array as you like.

**EDIT**: this looks like a good answer using a similar approach…https://stackoverflow.com/a/22487898/2379433.  Also this also seems to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27027632/2379433.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!