# Multiprocessing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Is it possible to partition a pandas dataframe to do multiprocessing?

Specifically, my DataFrames are simply too big and take several minutes to run even one transformation on a single processor.

I know, I could do this in Spark but a lot of code has already been written, so preferably I would like to stick with what I have and get parallel functionality.

Comment: take a look at [Dask project](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? multiprocessing seem to work with pandas - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187759/parallelize-apply-after-pandas-groupby

Comment: [Dask Examples](https://github.com/dask/dask-examples)

Comment: Hey Torrinos, it seems like the answers were specific to applying on a groupby object. I have a bunch of apply statements over rows on a whole dataframe. Instead of running the whole dataframe on a single processor, I would like to parallelize it over multiple processors.

Comment: Hey Max, dask seems promising, but is it in any way connected to pandas? If it's a child of pandas DataFrame then I can use it. Otherwise, it's too dangerous - it will probably blow up a large portion of my code.

Comment: Dask looks like a great answer. Thanks MaxU!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly modifying https://stackoverflow.com/a/29281494/5351271 I could get a solution to work over rows.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def applyParallel(dfGrouped, func):
    with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
        ret_list = p.map(func, [group for name, group in dfGrouped])
    return pandas.concat(ret_list)

def apply_row_foo(input_df):
    return input_df.apply((row_foo), axis=1)

n_chunks = 10

grouped = df.groupby(df.index // n_chunks)
applyParallel(grouped, apply_row_foo)
```

If the index is not merely a row number, just group by np.arange(len(df)) // n_chunks

Decidedly not elegant, but worked in my use case.