# Pandas parallel groupBy consumes tons of memory

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a medium sized file (~300MB) containing a list of individuals (~300k) and actions they performed. I'm trying to apply an operation for each individuals using `groupBy` and the paralellized version of `apply` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187759/parallelize-apply-after-pandas-groupby). It looks something like this

```
import pandas
import multiprocessing
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

df = pandas.read_csv(src)
patients_table_raw = apply_parallel(df.groupby('ID'), f)

def applyParallel(dfGrouped, func):
    retLst = Parallel(n_jobs=multiprocessing.cpu_count())(delayed(func)(group) for name, group in dfGrouped)
    return pd.concat(retLst)
```

But unfortunately this consumes A HELL LOT OF SPACE. I think it is related with the fact that the simple command:

```
list_groups = list(df.groupby('ID'))
```

Consumes several GB of memory! How to procceed? My initial thoughts were to iterate the groupBy in small 'stacks', not consuming too much memory (but I didn't found a way to do so without casting it to a list).

### More detailed context

I have a simple CSV dataset in the following fashion:

```
|-------------------------|
| ID | Timestamp | Action |
|-------------------------|
|1   | 0         | A      |
|1   | 10        | B      |
|1   | 20        | C      |
|2   | 0         | B      |
|2   | 15        | C      |
         ...
```

What I'm basically trying to do is create a different table that contains a description of sequence of actions/timestamps of the individuals and their IDs. This will help me retrieve the individuals

```
|------------------|
| ID | Description |
|------------------|
|1   | 0A10B20C    |
|2   | 0B15C       |
         ...
```

In order to do so, and to follow a Pythonic way, my idea was basically to load the first table in a pandas DataFrame, groupBy the ID, and apply a function in the grouping that returns a row of the table I want for each group (each ID). However, I have LOTS of individuals in my dataset (around 1 million), and the groupBy operation was extremely expensive (without explicit garbage collection, as I mentioned in my own answer). Also, parallelizing the groupBy implied in significant memory use, because apparently some things get duplicated.

Therefore, the more detailed question is: how to use groupBy (and therefore make the data processing faster than if you would implement a loop of your own) and don't get this huge memory overhead?

Comment: There is an alternative! use Apache Spark. :D

Comment: Hahaha, is supposed to be a one off thing, so I didn't want to get fancy! But reasonable approach! Thanks

Comment: Do you actually need parallelization on a file that sized?  A lot easier to just work in serial.  If you do need it, look at `dask`.

Comment: `dask` is exactly designed to address your issue by keeping exactly the way you work with your dataframes. No additional Java Spark fanciness to add.

Comment: I agree with @chrisb - I don't think you need to parallelize your computations - very often it will be slower when using Pandas. Can you post a question with a sample data set, short description of what you are going to achieve and desired data set - in this case the SO community might be able to find an optimal solution

Comment: @MaxU tried to explain a bit more! Hopefully there exists a more elegant solution than mine.

Comment: @ManoelRibeiro, i've added an answer - could you check it with your real data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments and then the solution I've found:

- I've tried `dask` and it didn't made much difference. I guess it is because the file is not big enough to use the secondary memory.
- The memory performance improves significantly if you perform the garbage collection inside the function you apply to the groups. I've managed to do so with a simple `gc.collect()` that happens every $10000$ interactions. Something like:

  ```
  x['ID'].head(1).values[0] % 10000 == 0:
      gc.collect()
  ```
- The garbage collection actually made my parallel version run. But the `return pd.concat(retLst)` was another huge bottleneck, and consumed tons of memory!

My final solution was to paralellize the solution in an outer fashion:

- I created a function that will perform the groupBy and the apply for individuals with ID's inside a range [X,Y]
- I simply create a pool and run those in parallel. Each process saves a file with a different name, depending on its range

  ```
  f = functools.partial(make_patient_tables2, src="in", dest="out")
  range_of = [(0, 10000), (10000, 20000), (20000, 30000)]
  with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
      ret_list = p.map(f, range_of)
  ```
- Last but not least, I concatenate all the generated files.

Notice that this is still a bit memory intensive, as we have to replicate the reading of the table (which is done inside *make_patient_tables2*, but would happen anyway, as the multiprocessing doesn't share resources. A better solution, therefore, would envolve sharing resources, but the garbage collector + not using the concat + replication the original data only 2-3 times was enough for me!

Certainly not pretty. Hope it can be of help for someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (**without** parallelization):

```
In [87]: df
Out[87]:
   ID  Timestamp Action
0   1          0      A
1   1         10      B
2   1         20      C
3   2          0      B
4   2         15      C

In [88]: df.set_index('ID').astype(str).sum(axis=1).groupby(level=0).sum().to_frame('Description').reset_index()
Out[88]:
   ID Description
0   1    0A10B20C
1   2       0B15C
```

Comment: Hey! I've tried it, and is efficient. Curiously the garbage collection problem doesn't happen in your approach. However this approach is not totally generalizable (actually in the true dataset you have a bit more complicated description and tables), and therefore you kinda "need" the apply, as the mere sum won't solve it. I wonder if by applying the generic function you create all the problems I've had.

Comment: @ManoelRibeiro, `.apply()` in general is pretty inefficient, so we want to avoid it if possible