# Speeding up Time Series bootstrapping

Tags: pandas, performance, time-series, simulation

I want to perform bootstrapping to time series data and then apply to each different sample a function to calculate various metrics.

The bootstrapping itself, that is simulating different samples is sufficiently fast. But the problem is when I want to apply the function to each sample. Usually, I am working with over 10000 different samples.

Here is a MWE:

```
import yfinance
from arch.bootstrap import IIDBootstrap
import pandas as pd
import quantstats as qs

def BootstrapIDD(series: pd.Series = None, n_samples: int = 1000):
    nobs = len(series)
    bsidd = IIDBootstrap(series)
    ps_list = []
    row_range = range(0, nobs)
    for pos_data in bsidd.bootstrap(reps=n_samples):
        new_sample = pos_data[0][0]
        new_sample.index = row_range
        ps_list.append(new_sample)

    df = pd.concat(ps_list, axis=1)

    # cleaning
    string_name = series.name
    cols = [string_name + '_path_' + str(x) for x in range(1, n_samples + 1)]
    df.columns = cols
    df.index = ret_bench.index

    return df

data = yfinance.download('^GSPC')
ret_bench = data['Adj Close'].pct_change()
ret_bench.name ='SP500'

func = qs.stats.adjusted_sortino
df_results = BootstrapIDD(ret_bench, n_samples=10000)
 
df_func = df_results.apply(func)
```

The slow part is this line:  `df_func = df_results.apply(func)`

Can someone help improve the speed of this last part where I apply this function across all columns of my dataframe?

**UPDATE**

the `func` in this example takes as inputs a dataframe and is pretty fast. In general, however, not all the function I want to apply across columns can do this, so it is still an issue to find an alternative to the `df.apply(func)`

Comment: Pay attention to the library parallel-pandas. There is parallel apply method. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74542818/16591526

Comment: It seems that `df_func = func(df_results)` return the same values, and it is pretty faster

Comment: @Ben.T Yes, maybe the wrong choice of function. But more generally not all functions take dataframes as inputs, so I might still need to loop over columns. But I will make the update.

Comment: @padu it worked indeed. But what the argument `raw` is doing? I couldn't find any information for it and in this case, I had to set it to false in order for my example to work.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, a solution that worked with pretty fast results was:

```
from parallel_pandas import ParallelPandas

ParallelPandas.initialize(n_cpu=7, disable_pr_bar=False)

df_results.p_apply(func, raw=False, executor='processes')
```