# How to speedup a dataframe's apply function on a custom input function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with millions of rows. I want to compute another column `new_col` based on an existing `col`.

```
  df["new_col"] = (df["col"].apply(my_obj.move, args=(1,)))
```

`my_obj` is a class instance with an `instance` method `move` that takes in a value and some constant (`1` in this case) and does some numerical operations before returning it.

My script is stuck on this line where it's taking hours (and counting) to execute. How can I speed up this operation?

Comment: Of course optimizing the move method (which you haven't shown us) is one thing.  However, parallelization is your other option.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284989/parallelize-pandas-apply.

Comment: how many distinct values of "col" are there?

Comment: `pandas` works fastest if it broadcasts operations on fundamental types instead of doing value by value applies. Lets suppose these are floats and your move is a set of numerical operations. it may be that `my_obj.move(df["col"], 1)` already works. Those calculations would be applied to the entire column and without the extra expense of creating python's float objects. If it doesn't just work, can it be refactored to use pandas optimally?

Comment: @JonSG hmmm that's a good point. let me check. i think it should be O(100), so i think that might be one solution

Comment: You might get some nice sppedup just using a decorator on `.move()` from [cachetools](https://pypi.org/project/cachetools/)

Comment: You would have to give us an example of your move method and a small test dataset (so we know your value type) to work this any better.

Answer (score 0):

`apply` is expensive because `pandas` values have to be converted to Python values and the applied function has to be called for each value. Pandas is built to broadcast numerical operations over the entire dataset and that can be much faster than apply. That's a good part of why pandas exists.

Let's take an example column of integers and a simple calculation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

df = pd.DataFrame({"col":np.arange(10000)})

class MyObj:
    
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.pos = position
        
    def move(self, value, offset):
        return value * self.pos + offset
    
my_obj = MyObj(1)

print("apply", 
    timeit('df["col"].apply(my_obj.move, args=(1,))', 
    globals=globals(), number=1000))
print("broadcast", 
    timeit('my_obj.move(df["col"], 1)', 
    globals=globals(), number=1000))
```

Output

```
apply 4.777549560996704
broadcast 0.12983754099695943
```

That's pretty good!