# Parallelize groupby with multiple arguments

Tags: python, pandas

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187759/parallelize-apply-after-pandas-groupby) on parallelizing groupby. However, it can't be translated one-to-one into the case where there's multiple arguments - unless I'm mistaken.

Is the following a correct way of doing it? Is there a better way? (Especially getting the index appeared quite inefficient).

```
def applyParallel(dfGrouped, func, *args):
    with Pool(cpu_count() - 2) as p:
        ret_list = p.starmap(func, zip([group for name, group in dfGrouped], repeat(*args)))

    index = [name for name, group in dfGrouped]
    return pd.Series(index=index, data=ret_list)
```

which one would call using `applyParallel(df.groupby(foo), someFunc, someArgs)`.

Answer (score 4):

First caveat, unless your data is fairly large, you may not see much (or any) benefit to parallelization.

Rather than working directly with a multiprocessing pool, the easiest way to do this now would be to try [`dask`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-overview.html) - it gives a pandas-like api, mostly managing the parallelism for you.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000000, 10), columns=list('qwertyuiop'))

df['key'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=len(df))

import dask.dataframe as dd

# want a partition size small enough to easily fit into memory
# but large enough to make the overhead worth it
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=4)

%timeit df.groupby('key').sum()
1 loop, best of 3: 1.05 s per loop

# calculated in parallel on the 4 partitions
%timeit ddf.groupby('key').sum().compute()
1 loop, best of 3: 695 ms per loop
```

Note that by default, dask uses a thread-based scheduler for dataframes, which is faster for functions like `sum` that release the GIL.  If you are applying custom python functions (which will need the GIL), you may see better performance with the multi-processing schedule.

```
dask.set_options(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following version. Python functool provides partial function which will help you do that.

```
from functools import partial

def applyParallel(dfGrouped, func, *args):
     p=Pool(cpu_count())
     result=p.map(partial(func, *args), [group for name, group in dfGrouped])
     p.close()
```