# pandas group by in parallel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parallel-processing, pandas-groupby

I'm having some trouble splitting the aggregation step of a group-by operation across multiple cores.  I have the following working code, and would like to apply it over several processors:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

mydf = pd.DataFrame({'v1':[1,2,3,4]*6,'v2':['a','b','c']*8,'v3':np.arange(20,44)})
```

Which I can then apply the following GroupBy operation: 
(the step I wish to do in parallel)

```
pd.groupby(mydf,by=['v1','v2']).apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x['v3'],[20,30]))
```

yielding the series:

```
1   a     [22.4, 23.6]
    b     [26.4, 27.6]
    c     [30.4, 31.6]
2   a     [31.4, 32.6]
    b     [23.4, 24.6]
    c     [27.4, 28.6]
```

I Tried the following, with reference to:[parallel groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29281494/8621705)

```
def applyParallel(dfGrouped, func):
    with Pool(1) as p:
        ret_list = p.map(func, [group for name, group in dfGrouped])
    return pd.concat(ret_list)

def myfunc(df):
    df['pct1'] = df.loc[:,['v3']].apply(np.percentile,args=([20],))
    df['pct2'] = df.loc[:,['v3']].apply(np.percentile,args=([80],))
    return(df)


grouped = pd.groupby(mydf,by=['v1','v2'])
applyParallel(grouped,myfunc)
```

But I'm losing the index structure and getting duplicates.  I could probably solve this step with a further group by operation, but I think it shouldn't be too difficult to avoid it entirely.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm still looking for an answer, but It'd probably be better to use a library that handles parallel manipulations of pandas DataFrames, rather than trying to do so manually.

[Dask](https://dask.org) is one option which is intended to scale Pandas operations with little code modification.

Another option (but is maybe a little more difficult to set up) is [PySpark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html)

Comment: I tried to use dask for my groupby operation, but everything I tried made it slower and increased memory consumption.